# How to make JSX factory function global to typescript project?

Tags: typescript, jsx, typescript-typings

I'm following the [TypeScript JSX guide](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html) to setup & play around with JSX **sans React** in a side project.

One thing that's very annoying that I'm running into: I cannot find any mention of how to globally expose the JSX factory function to the whole project. Also (though much less important), my `JSX.IntrinsicElements` structure is also not being globally exposed.

Here's my tsconfig:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2015"
        ],
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "jsxFactory": "generateElement",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "pretty": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "outDir": "dist"
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*.ts", "./src/**/*.tsx"]
}
```

The file where I declare `generateElement`:

```
export function generateElement(tag: string, attrs: string[]) {
    return document.createElement(tag)
}

declare namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
        image: any
    }
}
```

The file where I declare my `image` element:

```
export function image(prop: {src: string}) {
    return (
        <img />
    )
}
```

And the main entrypoint for the project, where I try to import my element:

```
import {image} from "./image";

image({src: "google.com"})
```

The errors:

```
src/image.tsx:13:9 - error TS7026: JSX element implicitly has type 'any' because no interface 'JSX.IntrinsicElements' exists.

13         <img />
           ~~~~~~~


src/image.tsx:13:10 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'generateElement'.

13         <img />
           ~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make the function global, do not use the `export` keyword, that will make the current file a module and the function will thus need to be imported explicitly. Similarly, the `JSX` namespace needs to be global, so if it is defined in a module, it need to be explicitly declared in the global namespace:

```
declare global {
    namespace JSX {
        interface IntrinsicElements {
            image: any
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to go the global route this will work:

```
// jsxinfrastructure.ts
function generateElement(tag: string, attrs: string[]) {
    return document.createElement(tag)
}

declare namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
        image: any
    }
}

// usage.ts
export function image(prop: {src: string}) {
    return (
        <image />
    )
}
```

If you want the jsx factory function to be inside a module you will need to import the function:

```
// jsxinfrastructure.ts
export function generateElement(tag: string, attrs: string[]) {
    return document.createElement(tag)
}
declare global {
    namespace JSX {
        interface IntrinsicElements {
            image: any
        }
    }
}


// usage.ts
import { generateElement } from './jsxinfrastructure'
export function image(prop: {src: string}) {
    return (
        <image />
    )
}
```

The basic idea is that the factory function needs to be available in the context where you are using the JSX tag (if you can call `generateElement` jsx will work too).

Comment: Awesome. Helped me to declare  `import { jsx } from '@emotion/react/jsx-runtime'` that was inserted automatically using webpack using custom typescript transformer (emotion-ts-loader) like this: ```import {createElement} from "@types/react";

declare global {
  var jsx: typeof createElement = createElement;
}``` through *tsconfig.json* option `"types": ["./typings/index"],`                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */